# select div conditionally using xpath

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

I want to select a div only when the condition is satisfied/valid.

The following `div` can be present in 2 ways(button will be enabled/disabled) when loading the html.

Enabled button state:

`<div class="buySellOrder_bso21ProductOption__9UpPt bodySmall cur-po buySellOrder_bso21InactiveProductOption__qrf7D contentPrimary">Intraday</div>`

Disabled button state:

`<div class="buySellOrder_bso21ProductOption__9UpPt bodySmall cur-po buySellOrder_bso21InactiveProductOption__qrf7D contentPrimary buySellOrder_bso21MisDisabled__86CjY contentPrimary">Intraday</div>`

I want to select this button only when its enabled i.e select div only when it contains the class `buySellOrder_bso21ProductOption__9UpPt` and does not contain the class `buySellOrder_bso21MisDisabled__86CjY`

I tried the following but its not working

`//*[(contains(@class,"buySellOrder_bso21ProductOption__9UpPt") and not contains(@class,"buySellOrder_bso21MisDisabled__86CjY")) and contains(text(),"Intraday")]`

Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: What scrape-tooling are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome extension which requires xpath

Comment: Please give a complete picture of what you are trying to do. Saying you are using a Chrome-extension which requires xpath is not enough

Answer (score 0):

I would try to eliminate the random strings in the `@class`-attribute and use the following XPath:

```
//*[@class[contains(.,"buySellOrder") and not(contains(.,"Disabled"))] 
and 
contains(text(),"Intraday")]
```

Explanation:
`[@class[contains(.,"buySellOrder") and not(contains(.,"Disabled"))]`:
since we use @class more than once, put the predicate on that @class-attribute. And use `not` like this `not()`

Comment: doesn't seem to be working

Comment: The XPath is correct. There is something else wrong with your approach.

Comment: I am using this in chrome dev tools but it does not match with any elements of the page.

Comment: Than the element is not there. To use xpath in developer-mode you use:
`$x(xpath-expression)`